# manage jsp mvc login and registration forms

Tags: java, forms, jsp, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee

I have this validate function. It validates a login form against the database.
Does java test the expressions `username.isEmpty()` and `password.isEmpty()` two times? The former in the
`if ((!username.isEmpty()) && (!password.isEmpty()))` , the latter in

```
if(username.isEmpty())
    error.addError("username", "Username is mandatory.");
if(password.isEmpty())
    error.addError("password", "Password is mandatory.");
```

?

Is there any internal mechanism which "stores" the first test's results, avoiding to redo the same tests? 
I would like to keep performances and, at the same time, I have to fill the error bean.
What about if I want to put more fields with more checks, complicated with regular expressions (ex. a registration form)? 
Would that function still be good?
The basic principle I want to follow is: assign true to a flag(or enter in a piece of code) ONLY if I pass all the tests. Otherwise, it will be false (by default).
Not the vice versa (a flag true by default, which could become false).

Please feel free to correct my English if it sounds bad. thanks.

```
public boolean validate(FormBean bean, FormErrorBean error)
    {
        // the validation flag
        boolean valid = false;

        if (bean instanceof LoginFormBean)
        {
            // check not null
            if (!bean.isEmpty())
            {
                String username = ((LoginFormBean) bean).getUsername();
                String password = ((LoginFormBean) bean).getPassword();

                if ((!username.isEmpty()) && (!password.isEmpty()))
                {
                    // create the DAO
                    UserDao uDao = new UserDao();

                    // check the user
                    valid = uDao.checkUser((LoginFormBean) bean);

                    // set the validation status of the bean
                    ((LoginFormBean) bean).setValid(valid);

                    // add the error, if any
                    if (!valid)
                        error.addError("Either the username is not valid or the password is wrong.");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(username.isEmpty())
                        error.addError("username", "Username is mandatory.");
                    if(password.isEmpty())
                        error.addError("password", "Password is mandatory.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // add the empty error...
                error.addError("Both the username and password are missing.");
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the test expressions will be run twice.

If you intend to run username.isEmpty() and password.isEmpty() many many times, you could first store them as booleans. This may in theory save you a tiny amount of overhead. However, given that you probably won't need that result *that* many times, any performance gain is negligible.

If you're adding more unique checks using regex, I can't image you needing to reuse their results. I think your code is structured just fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Does java test the expressions username.isEmpty() and
>   password.isEmpty() two times?

Yes if you call the same method 2 times.

> Is there any internal mechanism which "stores" the first test's
>   results, avoiding to redo the same tests?

You could try to store the result into two different boolean values (1 bit for each of them):

```
boolean isPasswordEmpty = password.isEmpty();
boolean isUsernameEmpty = username.isEmpty();
```

And use them into your tests.

> What about if I want to put more fields with more checks, complicated
>   with regular expressions (ex. a registration form)? Would that
>   function still be good?

If you would like to push yourself forward try using Spring Web or Apache Struts for form validation and authentication methodologies.

> The basic principle I want to follow is:
>   assign true to a flag(or enter in a piece of code) ONLY if I pass all
>   the tests. Otherwise, it will be false (by default). Not the vice
>   versa (a flag true by default, which could become false).

I think your next step will be: "Damn I need something more than a flag. I need user ID, Name and Surname...". So try using some patterns (like DTO to store what you need and transport data through application levels).

I'd like to suggest to you to pay attention to your code:

> if (!bean.isEmpty()), username.isEmpty() and so on

because is NullPointerException feasable. You should ensure that your Object are not null before try accessing it.

Hope that helps,

Bye